# mysql Сортировка по двум полям одновременно из разных таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица note, она может хранить запись о людях и машинах.

```
SELECT * FROM note 
  LEFT JOIN people 
    ON note.people_id = people.id 
  LEFT JOIN car 
    ON note.car_id = car.id
```

Как теперь сортировать по алфавиту по именам и названием машин?

```
note:
|id|people_id|car_id|
|1 |1        | null |
|2 |2        | null |
|3 |null     | 1    |
|4 |null     | 2    |

people:
|id| name |
|1 |Андрей|
|2 |Борис |

car:
|id|name  |
|1 |Ауди  |
|2 |Бугати|
```

Нужно получить

```
|id|people_id|car_id|
|1 |1        | null |
|3 |null     | 1    |
|2 |2        | null |
|4 |null     | 2    |
```

Comment: `Order By people.name,car.Name`

Comment: сортировака в данном случаи происходит по people.name,а после по car.Name выйдет 1.Андрей 3.Борис 2.Аудио 4.Бугати

Comment: Тогда таки приведите пример входных данных и структуру таблиц, сейчас ответ на ваш вопрос - походит на гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: *нужно получить* `ORDER BY COALESCE(people.name,car.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал `CASE WHEN (people.name IS NULL) THEN car.name ELSE people.name END`,работает чутка быстрее чем COALESCE(по моим тестам буквально на 10ms).